# switch statement registering as default when i input case triggers

Tags: c, switch-statement

switch not working quite correctly not sure why, thanks cheerz
disregard possible incorrect math ill figure it out later, or u can fix it too :P
it just skips to the default statement if i put c or C
the first two input seem to work fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int decider;
    double radius, height, circumference, surfaceArea, volume;
    const double PI = 3.14159265;

    printf("please enter radius in cm:");
    scanf("%lf", &radius);
    printf("please enter height in cm:");
    scanf("%lf", &height);
    printf("C. Calculate and display the circumference of the base of the cone\n"
           "S. Calculate and display the surface area of the cone\n"
           "V. Calculate and display the volume of the cone\n");
    scanf("%d", &decider);
    switch(decider)
    {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            circumference = (2.0f*PI)*radius;
            printf("%lf cm", circumference);
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            surfaceArea = PI * (pow(radius, 2)) + (PI * radius) * (sqrt((pow(height, 2)) + (pow(radius, 2))));
            printf("%lf cm sqaured", surfaceArea);
            break;
        case 'v':
        case 'V':
            volume = PI * (pow(radius, 2)) * (height/3.0f);
            printf("%lf cm cubed", volume);
            break;
        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `decider` has type `int` and you're using the `%d` format specifier to read in a value, which expect a decimal integer as input.  So unless you enter in a number that is the ASCII code for one of the given letters, you'll always go to the default.

You're looking for a character, so make `decider` a `char` instead and use `%c` to read it:

```
char decider;
...
scanf(" %c", &decider);
```

Also note the space before `%c`.  The space will absorb any whitespace characters, including the newline that finished the last line of text.  This is needed for `%c` because unlike other format specifiers, `%c` will read and store a whitespace character.

Comment: thanks, should i be in habit of always putting space before % even if d, f, or lf for similar reasons?

Comment: @babySteps Only for `%c`.  The others will flush out leading whitespace.

Comment: @babySteps — only 3 format specifiers don't skip leading white space: `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.  For all others, white space is skipped automatically.  It rarely does any harm to add white space; it is not usually necessary (except with `%c` in particular).